# Check expiration times jQuery cookie

Tags: cookies

I have set a cookie using the jQuery cookie plugin. I've set the expiration on the cookie to one hour, so after that time the cookie is deleted. I want to display the remaining time left until the cookie expires to the user by retrieving this info from the cookie itself. is this possible using the jQuery cookies plugin? If not is there an eloquent way to achieve this?

I've set the expiration in this way:

```
jQuery.cookie('Cookie', timedCookie, { expires: new Date(+new Date() + (60 * 60 * 1000)) });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to get a cookie's expiration using JavaScript. The only way to do this would be to store the expiration date somehow, such as in a javascript variable or in another cookie or local storage.

Here's an example:

```
var MINUTES = 1000 * 60;

var expireTime = new Date(+new Date + (60 * MINUTES)); // store the expiration time

jQuery.cookie('Cookie', timedCookie, { expires: expireTime });

var updateMessage = function(msg){
    document.getElementById('time-left').innerHTML = msg;
};

var i = setInterval(function(){ // calculate time difference every ~1 min
    var timeLeft = expireTime - new Date; 
    if(timeLeft <= 0){
        updateMessage('Your session has expired.');
        clearInterval(i);
    } else {
        updateMessage('You have ' + (timeLeft / MINUTES | 0) + ' minute(s) left in your cookied session.');   
    }
}, MINUTES);
```